# What jar file does liferay mail engine make use of

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay

Please could someone tell me what jar Liferay Mail Engine makes use of. I have already done an import like this

```
import com.liferay.util.mail.MailEngine;
```

but it does not seem to be importing anything.

Comment: How can you tell, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Am trying to use it to be sending mails from my liferay application using some SMTP settings from my ROOT.xml. I wanted to do what was specified in this article

http://portaldevelopment.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/sending-email-in-liferay-portal/

Comment: do you want the name of the jar in which this class is found?

Comment: Yes I want the name of the jar that the class is found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the `liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0-5.0.1` installation and this class appears in the `util-java.jar` found under each of the webapps WEB_INF\lib

example

liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0-5.0.1\webapps\1-google-maps-portlet\WEB-INF\lib\util-java.jar

liferay-portal-tomcat-6.0-5.0.1\webapps\0-alfresco\WEB-INF\lib\util-java.jar